# Any lib to convert timeunit by amount of time?

Tags: java, converters, timeunit

Input unit is second, then output unit varies by amount of time.

example :

```
50 -> 50sec // less than a min
80 -> 1min 20sec
3700 -> 1hour 1min 40sec
216040 -> 30day 40sec
...
```

Is there any java lib that can do this?

It will be perfect if it suppors `timeformat` and `i18n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of these mentioned in this famous java blog:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-time-elapsed-in-days-hours-minutes-seconds/

You can also get Joda on Github, I have used it earlier worked fine for me.
https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time